# Validating client ID, client secret of a google Oauth application

Tags: validation, oauth

I have a requirement where I need the verify if the client ID, client Secret of an OAuth app registered with Google is valid(that is if such ID and secret are valid or not)before the info is put into the DB.....I went through a lot of Google documentation but have not been able to find anything on this subject.
Basically I need a way to be able to authenticate if the entered client ID and client secret are valid or not ?
Any thing remotely close would be helpful.

Comment: This is an dated question but curious if you ever solved this. Going through the documentation now myself and finding it a bit sparse for the client secret use case. Thanks.

Comment: No. Could not find any documentation on validation of client ID and secret. Had to rely on the user providing my app with that information.

Comment: What is the use case for doing this? You should never have to ask anyone for providing client ID and secret for another API to your application. Otherwise, you are more or less acting as a authentication proxy to Google API, which is bad for you and your clients.

Comment: well, the client information that you are asking is owned by someone else. Ideally you are the one who should be created the Oauth client on google and using your code to access that information. Google assumes that you know you client Id. However, in your case you are asking someone else to create the application and provide your code with the credentials. Its risky but its not the use case GOauth is made for.

Comment: Verifying client id and client secret is upto the Authorization server (and not the client application). You as a client can only store client secret securely with you and use it for obtaining access token in return for authorization code. Authorization server (in this case Google) is the one who does the validation of client id and secret combination.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this PHP code and it works well.

```
function ProjectValid($PostArray){
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        ],
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query([
            'code'          => md5(time()),
            'client_id'     => $PostArray['ClientID'],
            'client_secret' => $PostArray['ClientSecret'],
            'redirect_uri'  => $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'].'://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].'/'.$URL,
            'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code'
        ]),
    ));
    $Response   = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    if($Array=json_decode($Response,true) and isset($Array['error']) and $Array['error'] == 'invalid_grant'){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```